# find Coordinates on a 3D hexgon

Tags: python

[Coordinates of the hexagon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZPed.png)
[[Hexagon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxviV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tww83.png)

Now I want to add coordinates between these coordinates such that these 8 coordinates 27 coordinates as shown[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr5G7.jpg)
an find the new coordinates too

I tried to make a code but not working much well
xi = [-1.0, 0.0, 1.0]
ele_arr is the coordinates given

```
cord1 = np.zeros([(N+1)*(N+1)*(NPZ+1),4],dtype = 'float64')

cord1[0,:] = ele_arr[-1,:]
cord1[N,:] = ele_arr[-2,:]
cord1[N*(N+1),:] = ele_arr[3,:]
cord1[((N+1)*(N+1))-1,:] = ele_arr[2,:]
cord1[-1,:] = ele_arr[0,:]
cord1[-1-(N),:] = ele_arr[1,:]
cord1[-1-(N*(N+1)),:] = ele_arr[-4,:]
cord1[-((N+1)*(N+1)),:] = ele_arr[-3,:]


for i in range(1,NPZ):
    gap = (N+1) * (N+1)
    cord1[i*gap,1:4] = np.array([cord1[0,1] + ((cord1[-((N+1)*(N+1)),1] - cord1[0,1]) * ((xi[i] - xi[0])/2)),
                                 cord1[0,2] + ((cord1[-((N+1)*(N+1)),2] - cord1[0,2]) * ((xi[i] - xi[0])/2)),
                                 cord1[0,3] + ((cord1[-((N+1)*(N+1)),3] - cord1[0,3]) * ((xi[i] - xi[0])/2))])

    cord1[i*gap + N,1:4] = np.array([cord1[N,1] + ((cord1[-1-(N*(N+1)),1] - cord1[N,1]) * ((xi[i] - xi[0])/2)),
                                     cord1[N,2] + ((cord1[-1-(N*(N+1)),2] - cord1[N,2]) * ((xi[i] - xi[0])/2)),
                                     cord1[N,3] + ((cord1[-1-(N*(N+1)),3] - cord1[N,3]) * ((xi[i] - xi[0])/2))])

    cord1[i*gap + N + (N+1)*N,1:4] = np.array([cord1[((N+1)*(N+1))-1,1] + ((cord1[-1,1] - cord1[((N+1)*(N+1))-1,1]) * ((xi[i] - xi[0])/2)),
                                           cord1[((N+1)*(N+1))-1,2] +  ((cord1[-1,2] - cord1[((N+1)*(N+1))-1,2]) * ((xi[i] - xi[0])/2)),
                                           cord1[((N+1)*(N+1))-1,3] + ((cord1[-1,3] - cord1[((N+1)*(N+1))-1,3]) * ((xi[i] - xi[0])/2))])

    cord1[i*gap + (N+1)*N,1:4] = np.array([ cord1[N*(N+1),1] + ((cord1[-1-N,1] - cord1[N*(N+1),1]) * ((xi[i] - xi[0])/2)),
                                               cord1[N*(N+1),2] + ((cord1[-1-N,2] - cord1[N*(N+1),2]) * ((xi[i] - xi[0])/2)),
                                               cord1[N*(N+1),3] + ((cord1[-1-N,3] - cord1[N*(N+1),3]) * ((xi[i] - xi[0])/2))])


for i in range(NPZ+1):
    for j in range(1,N):
        cord1[i*(N+1)*(N+1)+j,1:4] = [cord1[i*(N+1)*(N+1),1] + ((cord1[i*(N+1)*(N+1)+N,1] - cord1[i*(N+1)*(N+1),1]) * (((xi[j] - xi[0])/2))),
                                    cord1[i*(N+1)*(N+1),2] + ((cord1[i*(N+1)*(N+1)+N,2] - cord1[i*(N+1)*(N+1),2]) * (((xi[j] - xi[0])/2))),
                                    cord1[i*(N+1)*(N+1),3] + ((cord1[i*(N+1)*(N+1)+N,3] - cord1[i*(N+1)*(N+1),3]) * (((xi[j] - xi[0])/2)))]

        cord1[i*(N+1)*(N+1)+(N*(N+1))+j,1:4] = [cord1[i*(N+1)*(N+1)+(N*(N+1)),1] + ((cord1[i*(N+1)*(N+1)+(N*(N+1))+N,1] - cord1[i*(N+1)*(N+1)+(N*(N+1)),1]) * (((xi[j] - xi[0])/2))),
                                                cord1[i*(N+1)*(N+1)+(N*(N+1)),2] + ((cord1[i*(N+1)*(N+1)+(N*(N+1))+N,2] - cord1[i*(N+1)*(N+1)+(N*(N+1)),2]) * (((xi[j] - xi[0])/2))),
                                                cord1[i*(N+1)*(N+1)+(N*(N+1)),3] + ((cord1[i*(N+1)*(N+1)+(N*(N+1))+N,3] - cord1[i*(N+1)*(N+1)+(N*(N+1)),3]) * (((xi[j] - xi[0])/2)))]

for i in range(NPZ+1):
    for j in range(N+1):
        for k in range(1,N):
            cord1[(i*gap)+(k*(N+1))+j,1:4] = [cord1[(i*gap)+j,1] + ((cord1[(i*gap)+j+(N*(N+1)),1] - cord1[(i*gap)+j,1]) * (((xi[k] - xi[0])/2))),
                                              cord1[(i*gap)+j,2] + ((cord1[(i*gap)+j+(N*(N+1)),2] - cord1[(i*gap)+j,2]) * (((xi[k] - xi[0])/2))),
                                              cord1[(i*gap)+j,3] + ((cord1[(i*gap)+j+(N*(N+1)),3] - cord1[(i*gap)+j,3]) * (((xi[k] - xi[0])/2)))]
```

Comment: "I want to add coordinates between these coordinates such that these 8 coordinates 27 coordinates": what ??

Comment: i want to add extra internal node at particular distances such that these 8 outer corner nodes remains the same. but extra internal nodes are created to make 27 nodes when 1 nodes in between is added at every edge and face. As shown in hyperlink above under "enter image description here"

Answer (score 0):

Hard code it: let a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h be the eight points. Then add the averages of

(a, b), (b, c), (c, d), (d, a), (d, e), (e, f), (g, h), (h, d), (a, d), (b, e), (c, f), (d, h), (a, b, c, d), (a, d, b, e), (e, f, g, h), (b, e, c, f), (c, f, d, h), (d, h, a, d), (a, b, c, d, e, f, g).

Comment: can't use average as many times it is not even avg. Sometimes xi value is [-1.0, -0.447213595499957, 0.447213595499957, 1.0]
In this case total nodes would be, (length of xi)^3

Comment: @SAURABHAGARWAL; then your question is unintelligible.